# Which is Odoo website user group?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-website

I'm new in odoo so sorry if this is a noob question.

**How can I assing unlogged website user read permission to the model?**

**which is the website user group?**

And why odoo 8.0 documentation so poor?

I've made a module website_downloads:

models:

```
class Files(models.Model):
    _name = 'website_downloads.files'
    name = fields.Char()
    file = fields.Binary('File')
    filename = fields.Char()
```

controler:

```
class website_downloads(http.Controller):
    @http.route('/downloads/', auth='public', website=True)
    def index(self, **kw):
        files = http.request.env['website_downloads.files']
        return http.request.render('website_downloads.index', {
            'files': files.search([]),
        })
```

website template:

```
<template id="index" name="Website Downloads Index">
  <t t-call="website.layout">
    <div id="wrap" style="margin-top:50px;margin-bottom:50px">
      <div class="container text-center">
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <t t-foreach="files" t-as="f">
        <tr>
          <td align="left"><t t-esc="f.name"/></td>
          <td><t t-esc="f.filename"/></td>
          <td><a t-attf-href="/web/binary/saveas?model=website_downloads.files&amp;field=file&amp;filename_field=filename&amp;id={{ f.id }}"> <i class="fa fa-download"></i> Download</a></td>
        </tr>
      </t>
    </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </t>
</template>
```

security

```
id,name,model_id:id,group_id:id,perm_read,perm_write,perm_create,perm_unlink
access_website_downloads_user,website_downloads.files,model_website_downloads_files,base.group_user,1,0,0,0
access_website_downloads_manager,website_downloads.files,model_website_downloads_files,base.group_sale_manager,1,1,1,1
```

Answer (score 1):

"base.group_public"

I solved adding this to the security file

```
access_website_downloads_public,website_downloads.files,model_website_downloads_files,base.group_public,1,0,0,0
```